# No IP address in apache logs

Tags: linux, apache, logging, centos

I have a apache server running on CentOS 6.5 server. In log files 25% of records are like this

```
000.000.000.000 - - [24/Jul/2014:04:15:10 +0000] "GET /address/of/the/page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 20341 "-" "Mozilla/4.0
```

But rest of 75% of logs are like this, without IP

```
- - [24/Jul/2014:04:15:10 +0000] "GET /address/of/the/page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 20341 "-" "Mozilla/4.0
```

Can somebody tell me what is the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default Apache prints the REMOTE_ADDR header value in the access log, it may be that in your environment that value is blank in some cases. You can try printing the X-Forwarded-For header in the access log and see if that has the values that you need.

Typically if the requests are passing through proxy servers/load balancers its a good idea to check the value of the XFF header for the correct client IP.

Hope this help.

-Avijit

Comment: Can you give me some details about accessing X-Forwarded-For header?

Comment: %{X-Forwarded-For}i 
You can add this to the custom log format directive in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Avi's response, you will need to open the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and change the following lines:

> LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
>
> LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
>
> LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

to:

> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
>
> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>
> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
>
> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{Referer}i -> %U" referer
>
> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{User-agent}i" agent

Then, restart apache service with the command: sudo service apache2 restart
and the client ip will appear on apache log.
Check the result with:
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log